# Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: delphi

Должна выполняться проверка нажатой кнопки
за ней вычисление
....

```
case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of 
0:f:=cos(x); 
1:f:=sqr(x); 
2:f:=exp(x); 
end; 
if f>y then q:=f else q:=y 
if z>q then q:=z
```

....
Выдает ошибку в строке

```
if f>y then q:=f else q:=y  
Variable f might not have been initialized
```

В чем проблема - не могу понять, может кто подскажет.
все переменные типа `extended`.
Версия delphi 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это не ошибка это предупреждение, что объявленная переменная должна быть  инициализирована.

Comment: Точнее, что при определённых условиях (ItemIndex -- не 0, 1 или 2) переменная не будет инициализирована. Лучше исправить -- и компилятору спокойней, и людям.